# gdb doesn't show the source file

Tags: gcc, gdb

I have a strange problem. When I debug my code I can't view source for any function in one of the shared libraries. When I put a breakpoint on the function I hit the breakpoint but I get the following output

```
Breakpoint 1, omx_isend (ep=0xd10120, buffer=0x7fffffffd1d0,
length=70, dest_endpoint=..., match_info=1311768467139281697,
context=0x0, requestp=0x7fffffffd160)
     at <command-line>:1027

1027    <command-line>: No such file or directory
```

If I run bt in gdb I see the following

```
omx_isend (ep=0xd10120, buffer=0x7fffffffd1d0, length=70, dest_endpoint=..., match_info=1311768467139281697, context=0x0,
requestp=0x7fffffffd160) at <command-line>:1027
```

I don't understand why instead of the source file name it shows `<command-line>`.
The shared library is built with `-g` and contains the debug symbols.

Comment: It looks like that object file was built by piping the source code to GCC on standard input, so it doesn't know the file name.

Comment: is there a way to tell gdb where to find which function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why instead of the source file name it shows `<command-line>.`

As Jonathan Wakely correctly stated, this is because the input to `gcc` came from pipe. Something like:

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/' foo.c | gcc -g -o bar.o -xc -
```

> is there a way to tell gdb where to find which function?

You already know which function this is: `omx_isend`. Presumably you want to tell gdb that this function came from some file, e.g. `foo.c`.

I don't believe there is a way to do that in GDB. Your best bet is to adjust your `Makefile`. Instead of the `sed` above, do this:

```
sed -e 's/foo/bar/' foo.c > foo-subst.c && gcc -g -o bar.o foo-subst.c
```

Then GDB will just work (TM).